# Preparing/setup a SD card with NOOB using Linux

Tags: sd-card, linux, setup, noobs

The stages for preparing a SD card with NOOBS describe at https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/ are amid for Windows and Mac. At least, the part when formating the SD card is different in Linux.

So I wonder: which are the steps to setup a SD card with NOOBS using Linux? (in my case Ubuntu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very same.

1. format the SD card in FAT
2. move all files to the sd card.